# Is there an alternative for queryCommandValue for a span element

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to create an extension for the medium-editor, and need to add or remove classes with a span element.

I have got another extension which uses the "queryCommandValue" method which works well for getting block elements like heading or paragraphs

```
document.queryCommandValue('formatBlock')
```

I'm having trouble finding something that works with spans, I have tried using

```
document.queryCommandValue('formatInline')
```

But that just returns `undefined`

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands for a list of all the available commands.

Comment: I did check the documentation (found it after posting this)

I have now got a library to make dealing with ranges easier. And can get the information i needed with that, the library I'm now using is called "rangy"